# Отступ внутри таблицы на сайте HTML

Tags: html, css, табличная-верстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Создал меню, запихнул в таблицу, хочу прижать все элементы внутри таблицы к её краям.
Всё прижал к краям таблицы, но меню не удалось. Отступы по бокам сверху и снизу.

Подскажите, как убрать этот отступ?

Код CSS данного меню:

```
#menu7,
#menu7 li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu7 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #03658e;
}

#menu7 li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -.36em;
  margin: 0 1px;
  height: 1px width: 20%;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для Safari и Chrome */
  -moz-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для Firefox */
  -o-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для Opera */
  -ms-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для IE */
  transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация CSS3 */
  background: #03658e;
}

#menu7 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для Safari и Chrome */
  -moz-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для Firefox */
  -o-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для Opera */
  -ms-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для IE */
  transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация CSS3 */
}

#menu7 a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для Safari и Chrome */
  -moz-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для Firefox */
  -o-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для Opera */
  -ms-transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация Для IE */
  transform: skewX(45deg); /* Трансформация CSS3 */
}

#menu7 li:hover {
  background: #8AB8CC;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg); /* Трансформация Для Safari и Chrome */
  -moz-transform: skewX(-45deg); /* Трансформация Для Firefox */
  -o-transform: skewX(-45deg); /* Трансформация Для Opera */
  -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg); /* Трансформация Для IE */
  transform: skewX(-45deg); /* Трансформация CSS3 */
}

table td {
  border: 0px solid #000;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Нужно использовать `border-spacing` - Задает расстояние между границами ячеек в таблице. `border-spacing` не работает в случае, когда для таблицы установлено свойство `border-collapse` со значением `collapse`.

Comment: Вы меня извините, но на дворе 2017, используйте flex http://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35

там все то задать 2 параметра для ul, display: flex; justify-content: center;

Comment: Я попытался, у меня не получилось. Можете дать чёткий пример кода для моего случая? Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

например:

```css
table td {border:1px solid #000;}
table {
  border-collapse:collapse; 
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}

table td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

table td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Главная</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Новости</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Контакты</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">О сайте</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```